# While running ultimate thread group with multiple users in parallel, I'm getting 'Session Expired' message for the application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Please find below details,

Ultimate Thread Group: User:10, Initial Delay:0, Startup time:300, Hold time: 900,Shutdown time: 120
Once Only Controller: Login
Run Time Controller: Actions (Given Seconds: 1420)
Once Only Controller: Logout

If I run the group with single user it's executing the Login and Action sampler without any error But logout sampler is not executed.

If I run the group with multiple user, some of the samplers are passed and some of the samplers are getting fail with error message as 'Session Expired'. Here also Logout sampler not executed.

How to over come this issue in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Logout sampler is not executed because the thread is shut down before it reaches it. Your overall thread group duration is 1320 and your Runtime Controller is set to 1420
2. With regards to the "Session Expired" I can think of 2 options:

   - missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter), i.e. the maximum duration of the user session is shorter than your test duration. Have you added [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan?
   - your application gets overloaded and cannot properly maintain the user session, check its logs for any suspicious entries.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, Now Logout sampler is working. And I have initialized token variable using regular expression extractor in login sampler to transmit session data to other sampler. Even now some of the samplers are getting failed if I added more than one  users to run in parallel. It might be due to token ID mismatch between two users .